# Neo4j web admin

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to change the database that I wish to query? The gremlin console only shows:

```
==> Available variables:
==>   g = neo4jgraph[EmbeddedGraphDatabase [/Users/Development/neo4j/neo4j-advanced-1.5.M01/data/graph.db]]
```

In the same directory I do have another db. I'm unable to change the configuration property:

```
store_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

You can point to other instances but these are before the console is started. The changes are made to the:

```
../conf/neo4j-server.properties
```